LACP flapping between qfx1k and qfx5200 over SMF bidi
We have a dark fiber (span is 32km) and we have a juniper qfx1k-36q in side a and we have a qfx5200-32c in side b (in side b it is 2x qfx5200-32c virtual chassis) and light the dark fiber with flexoptix 100g bidi 40km and rx/tx light are in the range (rx light level is -4.6db and we add attenator and reduce it to -8 as well) the problem is when we configure this one interface as an lacp/AE the port start flaping but when we remove lacp and configure ip on it then it starts working perfectly,
here is side a config:
run show configuration | display set | match ae1
set interfaces et-0/0/19 ether-options 802.3ad ae1
set interfaces ae1 description x
set interfaces ae1 aggregated-ether-options minimum-links 1
set interfaces ae1 aggregated-ether-options link-speed 100g
set interfaces ae1 aggregated-ether-options lacp active
set interfaces ae1 aggregated-ether-options lacp periodic fast
set interfaces ae1 unit 0 family inet address x/30

side b
run show configuration | display set | match ae12
set interfaces et-1/0/29 ether-options 802.3ad ae12
set interfaces ae12 aggregated-ether-options minimum-links 1
set interfaces ae12 aggregated-ether-options link-speed 100g
set interfaces ae12 aggregated-ether-options lacp passive
set interfaces ae12 aggregated-ether-options lacp periodic fast
set interfaces ae12 unit 0 family inet address x/30

i also checked the interface errors and when i configure lacp it is showing Carrier transitions.
qfk1k junos version is 23.4R1.9 flex
qfx5200-32c junos is 23.4R2.13
any idea?

If you have only one link, why are you trying to run LACP?

in future i want to add ports to my lacp without down itme

@Blackmetal Then you could add the new port with LACP, switch traffic over and then add the old port to the new LAG.

Thanks i know this, but i want to look the current problem and solve this.

Remove the attenuator.
-4.6 dB is well within the receive range of the Flexoptix bidi transceivers I've looked at. Why do you think you need an attenuator?
With bidi, an attenuator works on the transmitted signal as well which could very well cause a link failure on the far side. I can't say why it relates to LACP but it's definitely not good.
For the LACP problem (from comment): you could very well add a future port with LACP active, switch traffic over (e.g. using STP port priority) and then join the old port to the new LACP LAG.
Also, I set both LACP peers to 'active', the tiny bit of wasted bandwidth doesn't hurt.

I thought this too. No attenuator needed when you are near the max distance on the transciever specifications.

I'd say "no attenuator needed when the receive power is nowhere near the receiver's sensitivity limit".

ok i will do this, but my problem is why lacp not coming up now!

That's a different problem now. The link no longer comes up or the LACP bond will not come up fully even though the individual link state is up? You could try setting it for 'periodic slow' instead of fast but it should be fine as long as the equipment and link are in good shape. Start with the interface statistics for any indicators of bad frames that would indicate link or light level issues or equipment problems.

i checked light level rx is -4.8db and t is 4.5db, I just have Carrier transitions which is related to link flap and the issue is exist only when I configure AE for this interface, when AE is not configured there is no link flap

Try removing the link-speed configuration from LACP. Also consider removing LACP entirely and keep it as a basic AE interface, does the AE stay up then?

when i remove these config they are up "set interfaces ae12 aggregated-ether-options lacp active
set interfaces ae12 aggregated-ether-options lacp periodic fast" but when i apply them they are down, what do you think?

it was related to the optics, i swap optics with another brand and it works, the issue was exist with flex optix 100g bidi 40km
